# What are the more idiomatic ways of constructing this datatype?

Tags: haskell

I'm creating a card game in Haskell where I need to know the color of the card for each suit.

Right now I construct all possible combinations of suit, rank, and color using `cardCombinations` and then filter the result with `cardWithColors` to construct the `Deck`

The requirement is I want the suits to have the correct associated color: Diamonds, Hearts are Red and Spades, Clubs are Black.

Is there possibly a more concise way to express this logic rather than first constructing all combinations and then filtering them?

```
module Deck (Suit,Color,Rank,Card,Deck) where

data Color = Red | Black deriving (Eq,Enum,Show,Ord,Bounded)

data Suit = Clubs | Diamonds | Hearts | Spades deriving (Eq,Ord,Enum,Bounded,Show)

data Rank = Two | Three | Four | Five | Six | Seven | Eight | Nine | Ten
          | Jack | Queen | King | Ace deriving (Eq,Ord,Enum,Bounded,Show)  

data Card = Card { rank :: Rank
                 , suit :: Suit
                 , color :: Color } deriving (Eq,Ord,Bounded,Show)


type Deck = [Card]

findColorForSuit :: Suit -> Color 
findColorForSuit suit 
    | any (suit==) [Diamonds, Hearts] = Red
    | any (suit==) [Spades, Clubs] = Black

cardCombinations = [(ranks, suits, colors) | ranks <- [minBound :: Rank .. maxBound :: Rank], suits <- [minBound :: Suit .. maxBound :: Suit], colors <- [minBound :: Color .. maxBound :: Color]]


cardsWithColors = filter (\(_,suit,color) -> (findColorForSuit suit) == color) cardCombinations

makeCard :: (Rank, Suit, Color) -> Card 
makeCard (rank, suit, color) = Card rank suit color 

makeCards :: Deck
makeCards = map makeCard cardsWithColors
```

I tried creating all combinations and then filtering the result based off a filter predicate to determine how to associate the color to the suit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These requirement are also known as an invariant and the idiomatic way is to avoid them if possible (make illegal states unrepresentable). Sometimes it is really hard and/or not practical to avoid all the invariants, however in your case it is really easy because the `Color` of each card is uniquely determined by the `Suit`. Instead of the `color` field you could just define it as a function.

```hs
data Card = Card { rank :: Rank, suit :: Suit }
  deriving (..)

color :: Card -> Color
color card = findColorForSuit (suit card)
```

This means that each `Card` is a valid Card by construction and you can just construct all possible combinations of ranks and suits.

Answer (score 2):

I would make `Card` only have the rank and suit, and then write a function that *calculates* the colour (by using your `findColourForSuit`, although this will be even simpler if you use a single pattern match, instead of using `any`, `==`, and lists).

You don't need to store the colour of every card, it's implied by the suit that you're already storing. In much the same way as we don't put a field `even :: Bool` on every `Integer`; we just store the integer's value, and when we need to know whether it's odd or even we calculate that.